Luau - Trying to remove duplicate teams, but code only removes 1 duplicate, and not multiple if there is multiple
I'm working on an older version of Roblox, messing around with it. (2007 client, to be exact.) An issue I ran into is that when the game is ran on a server, everything will duplicate per client, so if there's 1 person, there's 1 duplicate of everything in the game, leading to immense lag, and tons of bugs (I have no clue why it does this.) Starting with the teams:
local teams = game.Teams:GetChildren()

local save
local destroy

local debounce = false
local counter = 1

local function destroyDuplicate()
    while counter < 6 do
        for i, team in pairs(teams) do
            if string.match(team.Name, counter) and debounce == false then
                save = team
                debounce = true
            elseif string.match(team.Name, counter) and debounce == true then
                destroy = team
                if save ~= destroy then
                    destroy:Remove()
                end
                debounce = false
                counter = counter + 1
                save = nil
                destroy = nil
            end
        end
    end
        counter = 1
end

destroyDuplicate()

game.Teams.ChildAdded:connect(destroyDuplicate)

This code only deletes 1 duplicate. It does not delete multiple, and also when a new duplicate is made mid game, it doesn't delete either.

Is there a reason you are using the 2007 client? There is poor documentation for what is supported in such an old client and not everyone can test their code since Roblox limits the client you have to the latest.

Are you sure that this is the right problem to solve? If you have a bunch of duplicated teams showing up, it might be better to figure out why so many teams are spawning rather than writing code to remove them.
